# XPath on XML in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-sql

What is wrong with this???
My task is next: I have a XML file and I need to show all cities wheare are no Mick.
!!! Cities are not unique. So, for example, I has Mick-London, Tom-London, Charles-Paris. The right answer is Paris only.

Query is for SQL Server 2008.
Thank you for help.

This is XML:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<database>
  <persons>
    <person fio="Mick" id="1" />
    <work city="London" size="450" />
    <state>United Kingdom      </state>
  </persons>
  <persons>
    <person fio="Tom" id="8" />
    <work city="London" size="500" />
    <state>UK</state>
  </persons>
  <persons>
    <person fio="Charles" id="9" />
    <work city="Paris" size="450000" />
    <state>Frace</state>
  </persons>
  <persons>
    <person fio="Some_name1" id="10" />
    <work city="Brussels" size="30000" />
    <state>Belgium</state>
  </persons>
  <persons>
    <person fio="Some_name2" id="11" />
    <work city="Munich" size="30000" />
    <state>Germany</state>
  </persons>
</database>'
```

My current script is:

```
select @x.query('//work[not(//person[@fio="Mick" and @city = this/../work/@city])]');
```

Comment: Why is the answer Paris only? Mick is only in London...

Comment: Sorry, for confusing. In this XML answer is Paris, Brussels, Munich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that query. It has an inner query as the cities are not unique, so it first builds the cities for Mick in the inner query and then gets all other cities in the outer.

```
select 
    y.work.value('(@city)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from @x.nodes('//persons/work') y(work)
where y.work.value('(@city)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') not in
    (select 
        x.work.value('(@city)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
    from @x.nodes('//persons[person[@fio="Mick"]]/work') x(work))
```

---

As requested, this query will use only `query`:

```
select @x.query('//work[not(@city = (//persons[person[@fio="Mick"]]/work/@city))]');
```

Comment: Thanks. But this task should be done only via XPath or XQuery. Your solution is great, but is it possible to do it via XPath only?

Comment: Let me look at it once more.